# How to make a bootstrap form which guesses the result?

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4

I need your help. I'm making a form in bootstrap, where the user fills in a personal number. And the website needs to finish the other fields with that number. However the website shouldn't actually fill in. More like browsers do when you fill in an url.

Thanks in advance!!!!
Wouter

Edit: I'm also very happy with some names I can google. I don't request any code!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Also note, SO isn't a free coding service, you need to do yourself what you want to do, and ask for help if you get stuck, and not demand code as you just did. Cheers!

Comment: Do you mean that the same number should also be in those other fields?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I have made an edit to make it more clear that I don't request any code.

Comment: @souzan No, I have a database where every person has a number. So when someone types in that number into the website. The website shows than the name that belongs to that number. But on which topics do I need to search for?